# Purpose of "No action selected" toolbar button?

Tags: qgis-3, toolbar

At 3.8.3, there is a button on the *"Attributes Toolbar"* that is always greyed out.  When I hover the cursor over it, the response is `"No action selected"`:

[image: example]

The QGIS documentation makes no mention of this button.  What is its purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the documentation on the QGIS Website this is the [Actions](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html) identify tool

[image]

First you need to set an action to perform:

Here is some actions setup (via right click on the layer properties):

[image]

Here is a result of using the actions with the '**FeatureID**' selected

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Now I'm gonna learn about Actions!